# Can I move the hard disk from one 2006 MacBook with Intel Core 2 Duo to another?

Tags: hard-drive, macbook

I managed to find an identical copy on the second hand market of my 2006 MacBook. If something fails in my current one–as has happened on a couple of occasions—but the hard disk remains healthy, can I remove the hard disk from one and install it in the other, and continue from just about exactly the same state? Is there anything that ties a hard disk to a logic board, or can this sort of flexibility be used as a backup plan?

Answer (score 0):

So long as the Mac you are moving it to is capable of running the OS installed* then there should be no issues at all in moving it to another machine, even a different model.

*No Mac can run an OS older than itself.
For Sierra & later, the Mac must also be new enough to support it. Ref: [Apple KB - Can your Mac use High Sierra?](https://support.apple.com/HT201475)

Comment: I'm not sure it's quite so simple, and I think I blew the macOS partition by doing this, although I was encouraged by your assertion and went ahead and tried a one-year older Mac. Could it be that this requires at least the command-option-P-R dance?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to reset the SMC & NVRAM, or even to hold Opt the first time, so you can tell it which drive - but this has just been 'one of those things you can do on a Mac' ...since the 90's.